# Can't paste some characters in SQL Server management studio

Tags: sql-server-2012, ascii, management-studio-express

I try to copy the column value from query results into the SQL Server Management Studio Query window.

The column value displays a value like this: `CaserÃ­-o La Dehesilla`
However, the `-` character is not a regular hyphen character it seems, because when I copy the value, I see this pasted: `CaserÃ­o La Dehesilla`. If I paste the value in Notepad++ it does work correctly. How can I make sure I can paste this `-` character in the query window?

ps. it's not the font as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239038/copy-paste-issue-in-sql-server-management-studio).

Comment: It looks like SSMS has problem with **soft hypen** (SHY/unicode ad) character. [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/396270)

Comment: Hmmm...thanks. I need to run a query that replaces this soft hyphen with a regular hyphen...how can I do that now?

Comment: Simple `REPLACE` do the job [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/396294) `UPDATE #tab
SET val = REPLACE(val, NCHAR(173), '');`